# custom fluentvalidator

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am very new in using fluentvalidator. All I know is the basic `rulefor()` but when it comes to custom I m totally clueless. Can anyone guide me on this?

I need to validate a nullable bool property. I need to compare 5 bool properties is at least one of them is selected then it should return true and valid otherwise, it should return false and prompt an error message that at least one of them is selected.
 below is what I have come up with but not working.

```
public class NullableValidator : AbstractValidator<bool>
{

    public bool isQualificationSet(tblNeutralFileMaint neutral)
    {
        if (neutral.MediationCivil==false && !neutral.CaseEvalCondemnation==false &&        neutral.MediationMagistrate==false && neutral.CaseEvalTorts==false && neutral.CaseEvalDomesticViolence==false)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

I used this as like this:

```
RuleFor(n => n.IsQualificationSet).SetValidator(new NullableValidator());
```

can anyone tell me how? Been working on this for a few hours now. It does not show any error but does not work or go to the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do. Do you want this rule to execute only when the IsQualificationSet property is set to true? I don't understand the relationship between IsQualificationSet and the other properties.

---

Anyway, if you want to build a custom property validator then it needs to inherit from the PropertyValidator base class (AbstractValidator is for validating the top level object). There is documentation on this available [on the FV wiki](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#CustomValidator)).

So a custom property validator would look something like this:

```
public class QualificationSetValidator : PropertyValidator {
    // Default error message specified in the base ctor
    // but it can be overriden using WithMessage in the RuleFor call
    public QualificationSetValidator() : base("At least one property must be selected.") {

    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context) {
        // You can retrieve a reference to the object being validated 
        // through the context.Instance property
        tblNeutralFileMaint neutral = (tblNeutralFileMaint)context.Instance;

        // You can also retrieve a reference to the property being validated
        // ...using context.PropertyValue

        // here is where you can do the custom validation
        // and return true/false depending on success.

     }
 }
```

As an alternative to defining a custom property validator class, you can also define custom rules in-line by using the PredicateValidator (the 'Must' method) - this is a better approach if the custom logic is simple. There's [details on this in the documentation too](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Predicate).

Comment: thank u so much this solved my prob. the PropertyValidatorContext context was the one I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me just post my working answer based on Jeremy's answer.

```
public class NeutralFileValidator  : AbstractValidator<tblNeutralFileMaint>
{
   public NeutralFileValidator()
   {
       RuleFor(neutral => neutral.NeutralID).NotNull();
       RuleFor(neutral => neutral.FirstName).NotNull().NotEmpty();
       RuleFor(neutral => neutral.IsQualificationSet).SetValidator(new QualificationSetValidator<tblNeutralFileMaint>());
   }
}

public class QualificationSetValidator<T> : PropertyValidator
{
    public QualificationSetValidator()
        : base("Please check at least One Qualification type.")
    {

    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {

        tblNeutralFileMaint neutral = (tblNeutralFileMaint)context.Instance;
        if (neutral.MediationCivil.HasValue && neutral.MediationCivil.Value == false && neutral.MediationDomestic.HasValue && neutral.MediationDomestic.Value == false 
            && neutral.MediationDomesticViolence.HasValue && neutral.MediationDomesticViolence.Value == false && neutral.MediationMagistrate.HasValue && neutral.MediationMagistrate.Value == false
            && neutral.CaseEvalContracts.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalContracts.Value == false && neutral.CaseEvalCondemnation.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalCondemnation.Value == false
            && neutral.CaseEvalTaxAppeal.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalTaxAppeal.Value == false && neutral.CaseEvalEquity.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalEquity.Value == false
            && neutral.CaseEvalTorts.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalTorts.Value == false && neutral.CaseEvalZoning.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalZoning.Value == false
             && neutral.CaseEvalDomestic.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalDomestic.Value == false && neutral.CaseEvalDomesticViolence.HasValue && neutral.CaseEvalDomesticViolence.Value == false)
            return false;
        else return true;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going with something like

```
RuleFor(r => r).Must(CustomPredicate).WithName("request");
```

And

```
private bool CustomPredicate(Request neutral)
{

 if (neutral.MediationCivil==false && !neutral.CaseEvalCondemnation==false &&        neutral.MediationMagistrate==false && neutral.CaseEvalTorts==false && neutral.CaseEvalDomesticViolence==false)
            return false;
        else return true;
}
```

I've written a more detailed example here - http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2015/04/complex-model-validation-using-fluent-validation/