# How to validate primitive types with FluentValidation in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, validation, fluentvalidation

The question is, how to gracefully validate primitive type arguments in ASP.net core using FluentValidation?
For complex types, I have a dedicated library with validators and I register the assembly in Startup.cs of my service. It automatically handles the validation of the complex types of the arguments of the endpoints.
How can be the same achieved with primitive types? And what if those need to be validated in different fashion?
Let's say I have a simple HttpGet method, with 2 simple arguments, that need to be validated:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyPublicEndpoint(int age, int randomNumber)
{
    // Endpoint logic
}
```

So the question is, how to validate age & randomNumber with their own logic using FluentValidation library?
Let's say I have these 2 validators for each argument:

```
public class AgeValidator : AbstractValidator<int> { ... }
public class RandomNumberValidator : AbstractValidator<int> { ... }
```

Comment: Why you need to validate primitive type in your project? There are many methods encapsulated in  AbstractValidator<T>, Does it make sense to validate primitive type? I only find this issue similar with your question, Maybe you can refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706632/custom-fluentvalidator)

Comment: would not recommend but you could work with rulesets: [link](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#validator-customization). In my opinion, if you need validation you create a (view)model for the properties.

Comment: @XinranShen, yes, there are business cases where I need to validate those, w/o creating a complex type for it. Unfortunately the linked question didn't help. Thanks a lot for contribution anyway!

Comment: @lordvlad30, thanks a lot for your answer. The link to the documentation did help & I went with the "CustomizeValidator" attribute. I had a feeling that my issues should be solved with the "named" rulesets, but did not know hot to use those in the controller method. Will gladly accept your answer, if you post it. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you could create a request object (that would take the primitive parameters) and create a single validator for the request object (instead of creating separate validators at the API end point). Inside the validator you create separate methods or call other classes to perform your validation. Something like this.

```
public class MyPublicEndpointRequest 
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int RandomNumber { get; set; }
}

public class MyPublicEndpointValidator : AbstractValidator<MyPublicEndpointRequest>
{
    public MyPublicEndpointValidator()
    {
        this.RuleFor(x => x.Age).GreaterThan(0);
        this.RuleFor(x => x.RandomNumber).GreaterThan(0).When(x => x.Age > 90);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyPublicEndpoint(int age, int randomNumber)
{
    var request = new MyPublicEndpointRequest() { Age = age, RandomNumber = randomNumber };
    var validator = new MyPublicEndpointValidator();
    
    ValidationResult result = validator.Validate();
    
    // Handle your result.
}
```